# What is the correct way of sending HTTP POST with Postman?

Tags: c#, http, post, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm trying to send a POST request to a test-page on localhost via Postman, but I receive weird errors.

I followed this example, part 1&2:
http://www.daniellewis.me.uk/2014/02/22/asp-net-web-api-from-scratch-part-2/

In Postman, I try to send a POST request to

```
http://localhost:57472/person
```

The request is JSON, this is my object that I send:

```
[{"Id":"3","FirstName":"Homer","LastName":"Simpson"}]
```

I also tried this:

```
[{"FirstName":"Homer","LastName":"Simpson"}]
```

I always get an error in this function:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Person person)
    {
        var nextId = people.Count + 1;
        person.Id = nextId;
        people.Add(person);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Default", new { id = nextId }, person);
    }
```

Error-Messages: 
It is either:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er 
darf nicht negativ und kleiner als die Auflistung sein." => "Index out of 
range - must not be negative or lower..."
```

or:

```
System.NullReferenceException: "Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine 
Objektinstanz festgelegt."
```

What am I doing wrong? It should add this new person to the list, but it won't work.

EDIT:
Solution:
I falsely sent the object as an array.. it should be:

```
{"FirstName":"Homer","LastName":"Simpson"}
```

Thanks for your help!

~
S.B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that cause your endpoint expects a single `Person` object as seen in below code block but you are passing a JSON array saying `[{"Id":"3","FirstName":"Homer","LastName":"Simpson"}]`. You should just pass a single JSON object `{"Id":"3","FirstName":"Homer","LastName":"Simpson"}` else the deserialization would fail and parameter binding won't work

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(Person person)
{
```

**SideNote: Your endpoint is actually a `PUT` request then why are you making a `POST`? It should be `PUT` only unless your client doesn't understand `PUT` which is not the case with POSTMAN

Comment: Thank you! I understand now, this was not obvious from within the linked tutorial.. Forgive my lack of knowledge ;-)